# Best practices / patterns for building a specific complex form

Tags: html, forms, mongodb, input

I'm building a form for users to be able to query mongoDB. A user must be able to add their own "entries" so to speak so that the following query would be possible:

`fieldA` equals `someValue`

**AND**

`fieldB` greater than `someValue` **OR** `fieldB` less than `otherValue`

I would like the params to look as follows:

```
{
  :r4nd0m => {
    :normal => ['someField', 'lte', 'someValue'],
    :or     => ['someField', 'gte', 'someValue']
  },
  :r4ndom_2 => {
    :normal => ['otherfield', 'is' '42179'],
    :or     => [] # Not filled
  }
}
```

How would I have to name the `input name`s to accomplish this? Is there a better way to get complex form data like this from the page or am I on the right track?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does the submitted form input have to look like your example?  That is not valid JSON and will have to be converted into a proper MongoDB query.  It looks like some JavaScript conversion would be necessary to get from serialized form data to your format.

Comment: @willOEM I would like to parse it into a legit query myself. It just doesn't seem like I can build a HTML set of inputs with Javascript's help that translate 100% perfectly to a MongoDB Query. My problem is I'm struggling to have this happen at all.

Comment: Hypothetically, you could, since MongoDB queries are JSON objects.  You just need to build some logic into your object creation to properly structure your nested and/or logic and evaluation operators.  I'd be surprised if a library for this does not already exist for Node or Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/node-js/ as you can then use Node.JS to parse your HTML and the driver will handle the creation of the underlying document for you.